# Нюансы верстки под WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, вёрстка, css

Добрый день!

Верстается макет, который впоследствии будет прикручиваться к WordPress.

Какие есть нюансы и особенности верстки под данную CMS?

P.s: Верстка адаптивная (если это важно), плюс будет использоваться jQuery и jQuery mobile.
Сильно не пинайте - с WordPress сталкиваюсь впервые.

Просьба дать рекомендации, либо поделиться ссылками на статьи по данной теме.

Comment: IMHO, проще найти тему, которая вам больше подходит, и верстать прямо по ней. В противном случае вам придётся проделывать отдельную работу по превращению макета в wp-тему. Плюс - некоторые вещи в вашем макете могут быть завязаны на плагины, и это тоже нужно учитывать. А что касается ссылок - они все здесь: [codex.wordpress.org](http://codex.wordpress.org/) (например, [Design and Layout](http://codex.wordpress.org/Blog_Design_and_Layout))

Comment: http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%20wordpress&lr=213